# Manipulate StackTrace in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, crashlytics, stack-trace

**Summary:**
I have a stacktrace in dart, where I want to remove frame #0, and then have the whole stacktrace adjust (frame #1 is now frame #0, frame #2 is now frame #1).

**Details:**
I have written my own assert type function in dart, that if fails, will grab the current stacktrace and send to crashlytics.

```
static void asrt(bool condition)
{
    if (condition)
        return;
    StackTrace stacktrace = StackTrace.current;
    Crashlytics.instance.recordError("assert triggered" , stacktrace);
}
```

The problem is that crashlytics identifies each error based on the first stackframe. So all of my errors are being identified as that same error, because I am grabbing the stacktrace from the same method. I understand I could pass the stacktrace from the caller, but a preferrable solution to me would be to manipulate the stacktrace so the caller does less work.

Is this doable in dart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up getting a reliable solution.

I used the [stack_trace library](https://pub.dev/packages/stack_trace) and its provided classes Trace and Frame.

In the following example, trace.frames returns an imutable list, so I perform a deep copy. I am ok with this as it only runs on a crash anyways.

```
    StackTrace stacktrace = StackTrace.current;
    Trace trace = Trace.from(stacktrace);
    List<Frame> frames = trace.frames;
    List<Frame> newFrames = List<Frame>();

    // start at index 1 to omit frame #0
    for (int i = 1; i <  frames.length; i++) {
        Frame f = frames[i];
        newFrames.add(Frame(f.uri , f.line , f.column , f.member));
    }

    Trace newTrace = Trace(newFrames);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution!

Comment: With that package, you can also do it as simple as this :)

StackTrace.fromString(Trace.current(1).toString())

Answer (score 2):

I can't recommend it, but you could use `StackTrace.toString()`, do text manipulation on it, and then use [`StackTrace.fromString`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/StackTrace/StackTrace.fromString.html) to get a `StackTrace` object back.

But really I suggest that you [file an issue against firebase_crashlytics](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues) and request some mechanism to allow considering more than the first frame.